# Laravel 5 - Artisan = escapeshellarg disabled

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

Im working on Laravel, and couldnt run certain artisan command on production. The reason being `escapeshellarg` disabled.

I do read a few people pointing out that its a bit safe to enable it. However if you read this blog http://baesystemsai.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/security-issues-with-using-phps.html it looks like its not safe at all.

So how to enable this command and yet remain safe on laravel?
Thanks